# Stripe: how can I block a specific credit card number?

Tags: stripe-payments

We would like to block a payment from specific card number. But it seems like we have no way to determine if it's the same card number or not using Stripe API. The closest I can see is [Saving Cards](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards) which can return `customer.id`. But from testing, `customer.id` is different each time even if credit card number is the same. So is there any way that we can block credit card number using Stripe API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to write Radar rules within your Stripe account, you can write a rule to block a card if the card fingerprint matches whatever card you are looking to block. The card fingerprint is unique to a specific card so this would weed out any charges made using that specific card. The rule looks like:

```
Block if :card_fingerprint: = 'hr23f4S8u1aOxh5R'
```

This would be added by navigating to the Radar section of your Dashboard, then to the Rules tab. There will then be an Add Rule button.

The card fingerprint can be found either in your Dashboard in the card details section of a payment, or via the API by running the retrieve charge API call which returns the card fingerprint along with a whole host of additional info.

You can find that API call here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_charge

Comment: Thanks! Card fingerprint is what I've been looking for.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for making this my first accepted answer :)